# How to find average cost from from mean?

Tags: probability

A school breakfast programme offers bowls of weet bix and milk. The table shows the distribution of the number of weet bix in each bowl.

Weet bix cost fifteen cents each. Each weet bix requires on average eight cents worth if milk. The students eat from disposable bowls which come in two sizes. Small bowls hold up to three weet bix and cost twenty five cents each. Large bowls hold four to six weet bix and cost thirty cents each.

What is the average cost of a bowl of weet bix?

I tried going 2.46(15)+2.46(8)+25 but did not get the correct answer of 82.78.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Repare on the two types of bowls you have. The small one with probability $0.31+0.29+0.16$ and the big one with probability  $0.14+0.07+0.03$.
So the average cost is:
$ 2.46\times (15+8) + 25\times (0.31+0.29+0.16) + 30\times(0.14+0.07+0.03)=82.78$

Answer (score 0):

For each value of $n$, you compute the total cost of a bowl of weet bix, which is (cost of weet bix) + (cost of milk) + (cost of disposable bowl). To determine the average cost, take the total cost of a bowl for each value of $n$, multiply it by the probability $P$, repeat for all values of $n$, then add all the results.